# change column datatype from array to integer

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ddl

I need to change the data type of a column from _float8 to int4

```
ALTER TABLE "table" ALTER COLUMN "col" SET DATA TYPE int4;
```

results in `column "col" cannot be cast automatically to type integer`

```
ALTER TABLE "table" ALTER COLUMN "col" SET DATA TYPE int4 USING (col::integer);
```

results in `cannot cast type double precision[] to integer`

any ideas?

Comment: . . Why are you trying to convert an array to a an integer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff whoever made this table screwed up

Comment: @niga Create a new column and copy over the element of the array that should be an integer.  Drop the old column and rename the new column.

Comment: You could custom a function to do this.
Refer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/331422/279664

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to point out which element of the array should be used in the conversion, e.g.

```
alter table x alter column y set data type int4 using (y[1]::int)
```

[db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=795d9ed061d0eacb4ddde859856daf5b)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an *array*.  To fix this, you need array operators:

```
ALTER TABLE "table"
    ALTER COLUMN "col" SET DATA TYPE int4 USING (col[1]::integer);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=94e1c98b65d746c2b1a3af22a6f519cb) is a db<>fiddle.